# Is it still possible to root my Samsung Galaxy J7?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rooting, samsung-galaxy-j7

I'm trying to root my phone and I am at a loss. I am pretty new to rooting. So, not surprisingly I soft-bricked my phone but luckily I was able to restore everything with Smart Switch but I read about how updates can prevent rooting.

I've tried a variety of guides but I keep wondering if it is even possible to do at all as I keep seeing comments about how some phones are not able to root at all.

**Phone Information:**

- Name device: Galaxy J7 (2016)
- Model number: SM-J710FN
- Android version: 6.0.1
- Build number: MMB29K.J710FXXU3AQF8

**What I have tried so far:**

- [XDA guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j7/how-to/root-galaxy-j7-sm-j710fn-root-t3448389)
- KingoRoot
- KingRoot
- OneClickRoot
- Dr. fone
- TWRP recovery (which gives /Data error no matter what file system I change to in Advanced Wipe. It does work but the phone keeps bootlooping after)

Unfortunately the video with the guide on XDA doesn't work. Does that mean it is outdated? Should I maybe flash the firmware back to the original (before update)? Or is it entirely impossible? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The XDA link is improperly done, double-check that.

Comment: Yes, the link is invalid, see "...." in link.

Comment: Have you tried CF Autoroot method yet? This one seems to succeed on (almost) every Samsung devices.

Comment: Follow this thread: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j7/how-to/root-galaxy-j7-sm-j710fn-root-t3448389/